# How to know which user pressed button

Tags: python, button, telegram, inline, telegram-bot

I am making Telegram Bot and I have two inline buttons. I need to do that when the user clicks on a button bot would answer like "Hi @username". How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this! You need to add `username = "@" + str(message.from_user.username)` and then `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hi " + username)`

Comment: Please avoid using `+` for strings, use `f-strings` instead

Answer (score 1):

Any message objects that you receive contains 'from' as a key to the User object which contains 'first_name' and other attributes (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user).

With the [aiogram](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram) library, which I recommend, you can do something like this:

```py
@dp.message_handler()
async def get_message(message):
    await message.answer(f'Hello, @{message.user.username}')
```

Comment: What about telebot (PyTelegramApiBot) ? I am new to this so it is easier to learn

Comment: It works the same there. You can get first name by using message['from']['first_name'] inside your message handler function.

Comment: @AlexZab telebot is a bad practice.